# Anko doAsync Call Not Executing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, asynchronous, kotlin

I'm creating a project in Android Studio and at am using the Anko library to run an API request on a seperate thread. Said thread is simply making an HTTP GET call and parsing the data while the UI thread passes said data and starts the next activity.

The problem is, my program never seems to enter the doAsync block. I've posted my code below for the function I wrote for the call, it's called on a button click and when said button is clicked nothing happens. It doesn't stall, doesn't crash, nothing. Other parts of the activity will even respond.

Solutions I've tried:

- Debugging to step into the block, simply skipped over it
- Removing the try/catch
- Doing the call and parsing on the main thread (throws an exception)
- Putting the call in a separate function as it is now (originally was in the button listener)

I can't find anything really about this online so any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
    private
    fun asyncCall(n : Int) {
        doAsync {
            try {
                // Call API, store Place objects in placesList
                toast("streamJSON call")
                placesList = streamJSON()
            } catch (e: java.lang.RuntimeException) {
                // Error parsing JSON
                toast("Invalid Request")
            }

            uiThread {
                if(n == 1) { // Submit button
                    goToResults()
                }
                else if (n == 2) { // Feeling lucky button
                    feelingLuckyAlert()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `CountDownLatch` with `await` and also where are you calling `asyncCall` function ?

Comment: I haven't, I didn't think I needed to as I felt this was fairly simple. And I'm calling it from the on click listeners for two buttons which are in the onCreate() method. I thought this might be the issue but I don't think I can take said listeners out of onCreate().

Comment: Oh I guess the problem is with your `toast` that needs to be inside the `uiThread` have you tried debugging it inside the `doAsync`?

Comment: I added those to debug it so it should work without them, wouldn't that throw some kind of exception or something? I have tried debugging it, simply skips over the block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is jumping into the `catch` block because you can't `toast` on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare(). The solution would be call the `toast` in the `uiThread`

```
private fun asyncCall(n : Int) {
    doAsync {
        try {
            uiThread {
                toast("streamJSON call")
            }

            // Call API, store Place objects in placesList
            placesList = streamJSON()
        } catch (e: java.lang.RuntimeException) {
            uiThread {
                toast("Invalid Request")
            }
        }

        uiThread {
            if(n == 1) { // Submit button
                goToResults()
            } else if (n == 2) { // Feeling lucky button
                feelingLuckyAlert()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that and it worked, is there a way I can make it so if it throws an error it just breaks out of the doAsync block and displays the error?

Comment: I think you can do `return@doAsync` to return from the doAsync block on error

Comment: Or you could also `throw` the exception from inside and put the `doAsync` block inside a try catch block to catch the exception